Frase nunca pode começar no gerúndio?
Considere a seguinte frase.

Visando realizar um efeito comparativo, também realizamos modificações e testes nas implementações do código-fonte.

Tem algum erro com essa frase em virtude dela ter esse aposto que começa com um verbo no gerúndio?  Um revisor anônimo de um artigo que escrevi respondeu isso---mas sem dar evidências da regra.  Nunca ouvi falar nessa regra de que frases não podem começar no gerúndio.  Estou em busca de informação.  Obrigado!

Não vejo problema com o gerúndio, mas "realizar um efeito comparativo" não me parece ser uma boa construção. O que se quer dizer, "efetuar uma comparação"? Se sim, esta é preferível.

Concordo.  A intenção é dizer "fazer uma comparação"; "efetuar uma comparação".  Você tem razão.  Obrigado!

Também não vejo nenhum problema com o gerúndio em si, mas por que não simplesmente "A título de comparação, também realizamos..."?

Pode sim. Por exemplo, você pode ter uma oração reduzida de gerúndio no início de um período:
"Saindo antes das sete, chegamos lá na hora do almoço."
